Since $0.\bar9=1$, is $0.\bar9$ an Integer?
I've seen the following proof for $0.\bar9 = 1$:
$0.\bar9$ can be represented as ($0.9+0.09+0.009+\dots$) which is effectively $\sum_1^n 0.9(0.1)^{n-1}$. Taking the limit as $n$ approaches infinity gives us the geometric series $\sum_n^{\infty}0.9(0.1)^{n-1} = \frac{0.9}{1-0.1}= \frac{0.9}{0.9}=1$
Assuming this is true, can we call $0.\bar9$ an integer? Apologies if this is a simple question, I've no experience with number theory.

Yes, $0.\overline 9$ is an integer.

Yes, $1$ is an integer.

Sure, $1$ is an integer.

This is sort of like asking if $\sqrt{4}$ is an integer. Or if $\frac{6}{3}$ is an integer. Its not an expression that is written using only adjacent digits, but that is not the definition of an integer.

Yes. It doesn't matter how you represent a number. The property of being an integer is intrinsic to the number itself. For example,
$$
\pi \cdot \left( 1+\cfrac{1^2}{3+\cfrac{2^2}{5+\cfrac{3^2}{7+\cfrac{4^2}{9+\cdots}}}} \right)
$$
is also an integer since the quantity inside the parentheses is known to be $\frac4\pi$.

Cool theorem. Could you link to a proof of it?

Maybe start here. Continued fractions are a big subject.
